# Spark Streaming scala performance drastic slow

Tags: apache-kafka, redis, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I have following code :-

```
case class event(imei: String, date: String, gpsdt: String,dt: String,id: String)
case class historyevent(imei: String, date: String, gpsdt: String)
object kafkatesting {
def main(args: Array[String]) {

val clients = new RedisClientPool("192.168.0.40", 6379)
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("KafkaReceiver")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.0.40")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms", "20000")
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "3g")
  .set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
  .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")
  .set("spark.executor.instances", "4")
  .set("spark.executor.cores", "3")
  .set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", "true")
  .set("spark.streaming.backpressure.initialRate", "100")
  .set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition", "7")

val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "192.168.0.113:9092",
  "group.id" -> "test-group-aditya",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "largest")

val topics = Set("random")
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)

kafkaStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>

  val updatedRDD = rdd.map(a =>
    {
      implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
      val jValue = parse(a._2)
      val fleetrecord = jValue.extract[historyevent]
      val hash = fleetrecord.imei + fleetrecord.date + fleetrecord.gpsdt
      val md5Hash = DigestUtils.md5Hex(hash).toUpperCase()
      val now = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())

      event(fleetrecord.imei, fleetrecord.date, fleetrecord.gpsdt, now, md5Hash)
    })
    .collect()

  updatedRDD.foreach(f =>
    {
      clients.withClient {
        client =>
          {
            val value = f.imei + " , " + f.gpsdt
            val zscore = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis
            val key = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
            val dt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
            val q1 = "00:00:00"
            val q2 = "06:00:00"
            val q3 = "12:00:00"
            val q4 = "18:00:00"
            val quater = if (dt > q1 && dt < q2) {
              System.out.println(dt + " lies in quarter 1");
              " -> 1"
            } else if (dt > q2 && dt < q3) {
              System.out.println(dt + " lies in quarter 2");
              " -> 2"
            } else if (dt > q3 && dt < q4) {
              System.out.println(dt + " lies in quarter 3");
              " -> 3"
            } else {
              System.out.println(dt + " lies in quarter 4");
              " -> 4"
            }
            client.zadd(key + quater, zscore, value)
            println(f.toString())
          }
      }
    })
  val collection = sc.parallelize(updatedRDD)
  collection.saveToCassandra("db", "table", SomeColumns("imei", "date", "gpsdt","dt","id"))
}

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
}
}
```

I'm using this code to insert data from Kafka into Cassandra and Redis, but facing following issues:-

1) application creates a long queue of active batches while the previous batch is currently being processed. So, I want to have next batch only once the previous batch is finished executing.

2) I have four-node cluster which is processing each batch but it takes around 30-40 sec for executing 700 records.

Is my code is optimized or I need to work on my code for better performance?

Comment: I'm not sure about Redis but the way you are saving data into cassandra is wrong. There are APIs to save `Dstream` directly into cassandra, no need to collect and convert to RDD. Also try to use `mapPartition` instead of `foreachRDD`. You can look into the package `com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming`.

Comment: @vindev - Hi as you can see I'm actually extracting data from Dstream and adding some columns to each row and then saving it to cassandra. So, will this be possible the way you are advising ? and Can you share the updated code that you have suggested ?

Comment: Not sure about spark-streaming related problems but creating a `SimpleDateFormat` and a `Calendar` on each event is very resource-wasting.

`println` call an each event is very slow as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do all your stuff inside `mapPartition`. There are APIs from datastax that allow you to save the Dstream directly. Here is how you can do it for C*.

```
val partitionedDstream = kafkaStream.repartition(5) //change this value as per your data and spark cluster

//Now instead of iterating each RDD work on each partition.
val eventsStream: DStream[event] = partitionedDstream.mapPartitions(x => {
  val lst = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[event]()
  while (x.hasNext) {
    val a = x.next()
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val jValue = parse(a._2)
    val fleetrecord = jValue.extract[historyevent]
    val hash = fleetrecord.imei + fleetrecord.date + fleetrecord.gpsdt
    val md5Hash = DigestUtils.md5Hex(hash).toUpperCase()
    val now = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
    lst += event(fleetrecord.imei, fleetrecord.date, fleetrecord.gpsdt, now, md5Hash)
  }
  lst.toList.iterator
})

eventsStream.cache() //because you are using same Dstream for C* and Redis

//instead of collecting each RDD save whole Dstream at once
import com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming._
eventsStream.saveToCassandra("db", "table", SomeColumns("imei", "date", "gpsdt", "dt", "id"))
```

Also cassandra accepts `timestamp` as `Long` value, so you can also change some part of your code as below

```
val now = System.currentTimeMillis()

//also change your case class to take `Long` instead of `String`
case class event(imei: String, date: String, gpsdt: String, dt: Long, id: String)
```

Similarly you can change for `Redis` as well.

Comment: Not found : type DStream

Comment: use `import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream` I have added type just for the reference you can remove the type.

Comment: ok I did that and val partitionedDstream = kafkaStream.repartition(5) , What this statement signifies ?

Comment: It will create 5 partitions of your Dstream. Read more about partitioning 
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-rdd-partitions.html

Comment: Actually I have now started my job and I can see it is taking major time in partitioning records.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169748/discussion-between-aditya-jain-and-vindev).